# How can I make webpack externals available to jest

Tags: webpack, jestjs

My jest test is failing on `import config from "config"` with the error cannot find module, config is a webpack external set like this:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');
customConfig = {
  development: {
    externals: { config: { name: "Something", apiURL: "localhost:3000/api" } }
  }
};
environment.config.merge(customConfig.development) and then module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig();
```

How can I make this accessible to jest so the test doesn't fail;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a virtual mock for non-existing module in file like this:

**`./config.jest.setup.js`**

```
jest.mock('config' () => ({
    name: "Something",
    apiURL: "localhost:3000/api"
}), {
  virtual: true
});
```

and load it in [setupFilesAfterEnv](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array)

**`package.json`**

```
{
  // ... rest of the package
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./config.jest.setup.js"]
  }
}
```